# How does this css3 animation work?

Tags: css, animation

I wanted to draw a curved animation and after a lot of doing monkey coding I get the desired result. But I'm stuck how does this work!

Look this picture: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGGMG/embedded/result/)

[image]

Now look this picture too: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGGMG/1/embedded/result/)

[image]

I got the desired animation that is curved animation after just removing `left: 50px;` from `50% keyframes`

But, I wanted to know how this is becoming curved as it's initial position is `left: 50px;`, not? Even if I don't place the left value it should go like previous but amazingly it's curving. So anyone have some idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN - @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#When_properties_are_left_out_of_some_keyframes)

> **When properties are left out of some keyframes**
>   Any properties that you don't specify in every keyframe are interpolated

And it seems the values are interpolated midway from the current to the next given value, using the [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function), which is `ease` in your case.

When you change the timing function to `linear` for example, you get a straight line

```
#ball {
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGGMG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it now that how this works.

When one property is left(i.e. removed) then it's value is increased accordingly.

Example:

```
0%{bottom: 0%; left:0%;}
50%{bottom: 0%;}/*the left property is left(removed)*/
100%{bottom: 100%; left: 100%;}
```

In the above code the value of left in 50% is initial(animation from 0%) = 0% and end point (animation to 100%) = 100%. 
So here the bottom value will be the same defined in 50% keyframe but the value of left will increase accordingly that is 
from 0% to 1%, 2%, 3%, 4%, and so on. Likewise, if you left(remove) the bottom property and keep(add) left property then it 
will increase the value of bottom accordingly.

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wnP3/embedded/result/) to make your concept clearer.

Hence the demonstration in the question is being viewed curved.

By the way of this concept I've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wnP3/1/embedded/result/) to make a circular animation also.

P/s: the animation-timing-function rather than ease works differently.

Try this yourslef::[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wnP3/2/embedded/result/) by changing the value from ease to anything you want such as ease-in-out.